# Attempt to write to null array android studio

Tags: java, android

I've created a simple 'app' to put values from text to an array and it doesn't seem to work.. I don't know why..

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    String[] data = new String[2];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        gotoReg();
    }
    public void gotoReg() {
        Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Submit);
            register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    data[0] = "ss";
                    data[1] = "dd";
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

From this code I get the error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array
```

I did almost the same code in another app and it worked.. seems really wierd to me...

Comment: can you try to initialize your `data = new String[2];` inside your `onClick` method?

Comment: is there more code which could manipulate your member? since its not private and no setter shown, it could be set easily by accessing from the outside. Second question: When you debug in "onCreate", is this member correctly set?

Comment: I don't think he should initialize it inside the onClick method, because it's generally bad practise (in terms of performance) to do repeated initialization. But yes, he should at least try to do it in gotoReg() method, since array is clearly not initialized correctly.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with you code. Try to delete and reinstall the app to make sure you are not running a previous "cached" version.

Comment: @YCF_L Doesn't working

Comment: @HenningLuther What did you mean

Comment: then i think your use in another part of your code

Comment: @NikitaIvanov i mean if there is code which is setting the member somewhere else in your code?

Comment: @HenningLuther Just had to restart Android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, thanks everyone, just re-opened Android studio and everything worked fine.
Wasted on it several hours ughh

Answer (score 0):

Just put your code to get button reference after setContent view then,you can assign the values.

And you have checked the id of button?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add

```
data = new String[2];
```

to your gotoReg() method, before setting the onClick listener.